# On iOS, is there a way to add the method addTarget to UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uikit, uiimageview

I just found that a `UIButton` object has a method `addTarget` to handle UI events, but a `UIImageView` object doesn't have such a method, so we can't do it in code, and can't add such an Action using Interface Builder for a `UIImageView` object either.  A gesture recognizer can be used, but is there a simple way to add `addTarget` to `UIImageView` so that our code is not partly handled by gesture recognizer and partly handled by the `addTarget` method?

Comment: why not just use a button with a background image?

Comment: Agree with @wattson12: any other solution is simply overcomplicating things. If something needs to happen on click, make it a UIButton and set the image that was in you UIImageView to be the button's image for all control states.

Comment: so that button will look exactly like an image except it is tappable?  I suppose there might be side effects such as reversing the color of the image when touched but it might actually be desirable depending on the situation

Comment: @JeremyL UIButton allows you to select an image for each state, so you can set a normal image, and a highlighted image if you want a different effect. If you only give a standard image, the UIButton will add a darkening alpha effect over the button image by default

Answer (score 7):

It shouldn't be much trouble to add a gesture recognizer that calls the same selector that your button calls:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];


- (void)tapped:(id)sender {}
```

Comment: aha, my original concern was that I didn't want some UI handled by `addTarget` and some handled by gesture recognizers...

Answer (score 0):

Because UIImageView is not a sub-class of UIControl (Which is the superclass of UIButton), so my solution is to fake the behaviour of UIControl that have a tap gesture and create a addTarget:action method to the custom UIImageView so it will look like other UIControl classes.

I've created a Sub-class of UIImageView called SWImageView, in header:

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
```

in main file:

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    if (tapGestureRecognizer!=nil) {
        [self removeGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    }
    tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:target action:action];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}
```

Don't forget to enable user interaction:

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```